# how to make login page as first page laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8, login-page

i am trying to make the login page as a start page on laravel 8 i tried to delete welcome page to remplace it with login blade and get and i cant get any results

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

something like :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

and this is the middleware

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'directeur','middleware'=>['isDirecteur','auth']], function(){
    Route::get('dashboard',[DirecteurController::class,'index'])->name('directeur.dashboard');
    Route::get('rapport',[DirecteurController::class,'rapport'])->name('directeur.rapport');
    Route::get('detail/{id}',[DirecteurController::class,'detail'])->name('directeur.details');
});
```

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

first declare your route middleware, then use **Route::view** for rendering blade file. Based on [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#view-routes)

```
// Your middleware Route
...
//

Route::view('/', 'auth.login');
```

Comment: and how can i delete this path if i can return login blade as view ?
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login

Comment: Oh u mean delete route for **/login** ? Just delete if from web.php, And run this command : *php artisan route:clear*

Comment: i dont have any route /login in web.php :/

Comment: just run that command, it will reset route cache for your app